# Cloning repository inside windows server within LAN

Tags: git, tfs, remote-server, git-clone

I would like to be able to clone a repository from within a remote server. developments needs to be done on the server itself (mandatory).
The remote server need to access a repository on a different server.

The current procedure:

1. Clone the repo on the local machine (connected via VPN).
2. Copy all files and paste them to shared folder.
3. Connect to remote server, copy the files from the shared folder to local folder.
4. Do the necessary modification and deploy.

Is there a way to make it easy to clone the remote repository from within a remote server?

Installing Git won't be an issue on the remote server, the issue would be connecting to TFS (git) from an external domain server.

Comment: Why don't you clone the repository on the server?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the issue would be connecting to TFS (git) from an external domain server

Comment: This sounds unrelated to source control, and instead is about deployments. (You could access the repo from the server but you don't need to. Servers only typically need built code and/or a small subset of an entire code repo.) One popular solution to this is to use a build server or similar deployment tool which itself has a copy of the repo and enables either a button press or automatic deployments to remote servers. You tagged "tfs", so if you're using Azure DevOps it has these tools built-in. There are many other options (including some free) as well.